# $_SESSION not available behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: php, session, reverse-proxy, session-cookies, reverse

I have a site (rp.example.com) that uses PHP Sessions. It works fine when the site is accessed through that subdomain.

I have a Reverse Proxy setup so that the above site is accessible vie two different domains (anotherdom.com/rp & yetanotherdom.com/rp).
The $_SESSION variable is empty and does not update when taking action on the site through these two Reverse Proxy URLS.

I have read that "$_SESSION is tied to a cookie named PHPSESSID, which is by default available only to the exact domain name where you use it."

In my case, it needs to be available to those 2 Reverse Proxy URLs as well. Any way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: For security  SESSION is only available to exact domain name. This is to prevent cross domain hacking. (otherwise subdomain A (aaa.example.com) 's login may get access to subdomain B (bbb.example.com)'s data.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not using the Session for the purpose of authentication. Is there a way to have it available for the other two domains then?